# DocuSign : send envelope to account via REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign REST API (from a developer demo account) to send a document to an e-mail address that already has a DocuSign account (free account). The user gets the DocuSign notification in their e-mail but not in their DocuSign web interface .........Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a specific API that I have to use so that the documents go into the users' DocuSign web interface ( if the user has an account associated with the e-mail address ).
Cheers !

My request is the following:

```
--b2cb90e7^M
Content-Type: application/json^M
Content-Disposition: form-data^M
^M
{"status":"sent","emailBlurb":"Please review and sign this report.","emailSubject":"Patient Report","documents":[{"documentId":"1","name":"TEST006.pdf"}],"recipients":{"signers":[{"recipientId":1,"name":"Some Name","email":"somename@company.com","tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"xPosition":42,"yPosition":42,"documentId":1,"pageNumber":1}]}},{"recipientId":2,"name":"Some Name","email":"some.name@gmail.com","tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"xPosition":42,"yPosition":42,"documentId":1,"pageNumber":1}]}}]}}^M
--b2cb90e7^M
Content-Type: application/pdf^M
Content-Disposition: file; filename="TEST006.pdf"; documentId=1^M
^M
etc.
```

Comment: Please show your request so we can identify if you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that your scenario is as follows?

- The Envelope is being created/sent via API in the DocuSign **Demo** environment (http://demo.docusign.net).
- The DocuSign account owned by the recipient of the Envelope is a "Free Trial" account. (It's a "Free Trial" account if it's accessed via either http://www.docusign.net or http://na2.docusign.net -- this is the DocuSign **Production** environment.)

If that's your scenario, then the reason that the Envelope's never showing up in the recipient's DocuSign Inbox (within their "Free Trial" account) is because an Envelope that's sent from the DocuSign **Demo** environment will never be delivered to a DocuSign user's Inbox in the DocuSign **Production** environment -- and "Free Trial" accounts technically reside in the DocuSign Production environment.

If you want to test the scenario of sending an Envelope via API in the **Demo** environment and have it arrive in a user's DocuSign Inbox, then that user account will need to exist in the DocuSign **Demo** environment as well. You can either add that user as a new user within the same account that you're API calls are using, or create that user under an altogether separate DocuSign account by simply creating another "DocuSign Developer account" via the DocuSign Dev Center.